# numeros iguales while javascript

Tags: javascript, while

Estoy intentando hacer este programa, ingreso un numero del 1 al 10 y si ese numero es mayor o menor el prompt se vuelve a ejecutar hasta que los números ingresados sean iguales, viene el punto donde puedo ubicar esa concisión

```
    let c  =0
    let n = parseInt(prompt("ingrese un numero del 1 al 10"))
    var num = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
    while (n <= 10 ) {

 
     if(n > num){
      alert("el numero ingresado es mayor al numero  generado")
      alert("el numero generado es:"+ " "+ num)
     
      
    }else if(n < num){
      alert("el numero ingreado es menor al numero generado")
      alert("el numero generado es:" + " "+ num)
      
    }
    
    n = parseInt(prompt("ingrese un numero del 1 al 10"))
c++
}
 
alert("felicidades")
alert("los intentos fueron :"+" "+ c)
```

Comment: Debes describir el problema, para entender que sucede, sino tendríamos que adivinar que quieres hacer c:

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! falta codigo aca? el problema cual seria?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

te hace falta una condición de salida. Cuando los números son iguales, debe avisarte y salir. Lo he corregido por ti.

```
let c = 0
let n = parseInt(prompt("ingrese un numero del 1 al 10"))
var num = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
while (n <= 10) {
  if (n > num) {
    alert("el numero ingresado es mayor al numero  generado")
  } else if (n < num) {
    alert("el numero ingreado es menor al numero generado")
  } else if (n == num) {
    alert("abradacaldka");
    break;
  }
  n = parseInt(prompt("ingrese un numero del 1 al 10"))
  c++
}

alert("felicidades")
alert("los intentos fueron :" + " " + c)
```

Answer (score 0):

te falta agregar la una linea `else` que segun tu codigo a a compara cuando estos numeros son iguales.

```javascript
if(n > num){
      alert("el numero ingresado es mayor al numero  generado")
      alert("el numero generado es:"+ " "+ num)
     
      
}else if(n < num){
      alert("el numero ingreado es menor al numero generado")
      alert("el numero generado es:" + " "+ num)
      
}else{//este es el caso cuando son iguales
      alert("numeros iguales")

}
```

Sin embargo revisando tu codigo se puede mejorar un poco mas.

```js
let c  =0
let n = 0
var num = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
while (n <= 10 ) {

    n = parseInt(prompt("ingrese un numero del 1 al 10"))
    
    if(n == num){
      alert("numeros iguales")
      break;
    }
    
    if(n > num){
      alert("el numero ingresado es mayor al numero  generado")
      alert("el numero generado es:"+ " "+ num)
     
      
    }else{
      alert("el numero ingreado es menor al numero generado")
      alert("el numero generado es:" + " "+ num)
      
    }
    
    
    c++
}
 
alert("felicidades")
alert("los intentos fueron :"+" "+ c)
```